# How to see if a string ends with one of multiple characters

Tags: ruby, string, ends-with

I have this statement:

```
string_tokens[-1].ends_with?(",") || string_tokens[-1].ends_with?("-") || string_tokens[-1].ends_with?("&")
```

I would like to put all the tokens (`","`, `"-"`, `"&"`) into a constant and simplify the above to ask, "does the string end with any of these characters", but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is `string_tokens`? We can assume a string, but for clarity it needs to be defined. When asking for help, we need to see working code showing what you tried. That helps us see any errors you're making and lets us fix/respond with answers that directly apply to your use. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
CONST = %w|, - &|.freeze
string_tokens[-1].end_with?(*CONST)
```

Usage:

```
'test,'.end_with?(*CONST)
#=> true
'test&'.end_with?(*CONST)
#=> true
'test-'.end_with?(*CONST)
#=> true
```

You use `*` (splat operator) to pass multiple args to the [`String#end_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F), because it accepts multiple.

Comment: `CONST = %w|, - &|.freeze`?

Comment: very nice, real, +1

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex :

```
chars = %w(, - &)
ENDS_WITH_CHAR = Regexp.new("["+chars.map{|s| Regexp.escape(s)}.join+']\z')
"abc-" =~ ENDS_WITH_CHAR
# or with Ruby 2.4
"abc-".match? ENDS_WITH_CHAR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'hello-'

',-&'.include? str[-1]
  #=> true

',$&'.include? str[-1]
  #=> false
```